# Where should I put the <script> tag for sentry CDN in html markup?

Tags: javascript, html, sentry

I want to use the JavaScript SDK for sentry via CDN. But I am not sure what is the best place to put the `<script>` tag in the html markup.

I mean is the `<head>` tag more suitable for this? Or at the end of the `<body>` tag.

[This](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/install/cdn/) is the installation documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it should be placed inside the `head` tag, but it depends on your project.